# How to copy a tablespace to another database without using Data Pump in Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, export, rman

I have a database on a legacy system that has some data that needs to be exported to another environment. Everything I need is contained in one tablespace. Unfortunately, I am unable to use Data Pump due to previously botched patching (thousands of invalid objects, including streams packages, which can't be recompiled).

Can I use RMAN or other methods to back up this tablespace, move it to another network (by physical media transfer - networks are completely segregated) and restore it to an existing database?

Comment: What about using the [original export and import](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#g1070082) features (e.g. *exp* and *imp*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bare minimum assuming the simplest scenario.

**1. Original export/import:**

Source database:

- export everything from the tablespace

`exp userid=user/password tablespaces=example file=example.dmp`

Destination:

- copy example.dmp from source
- create empty tablespace at the desired location, create users manually, then:

`imp userid=user/password full=y file=example.dmp`

**or 2. Transportable tablespace with original export/import:**

Source database:

- put tablespace into read only mode:

`alter tablespace example read only;`

- export metadata for transporting the tablespace

`exp userid=\'/ as sysdba\' transport_tablespace=y tablespaces=example file=example_tts.dmp`

Note that you get an EXP-00044 error here if you do not connect with SYSDBA.

Destination database:

- copy example_tts.dmp from source
- copy the datafile itself from source to the desired location (example01.dbf in below example)
- create users manually, then:

`imp userid=\'/ as sysdba\' transport_tablespace=y datafiles=/oradata/S112/example01.dbf file=example_tts.dmp`

- finally make the tablespace writable:

`alter tablespace example read write;`

More details can be found in the documentation:

[Original Export](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm#SUTIL3634)

[Original Import](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#SUTIL001)